# IBM DB Persistence Model

Tags: ibm-mq

I am trying to understand the persistence model of IBM MQ. I realize that the messages are stored in file based system but is there a way I can store the files in DB. I have come across article that states that the messages can be stored in the DB2 database, but I would like to know if I can store in other databases such as Oracle DB or SQLite or No-SQL Db's.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be misinterpreting the article. (A link would be nice.)  Early versions of MQ were closely intertwined with IBM's database at the time and much of the product retains traces of that heritage in names, sizes of data structures, and some functional constraints.

However modern MQ's primary use of database is in the coupling facility in support of shared queues, and this is z/OS only.  However that's the exception and for the vast majority of MQ versions and platforms you don't have the ability to select the queue persistence mechanism.

Remember that IBM's MQ was never intended to be a queueing front-end database client.  MQ was invented to address problems of synchronous communication in which the outage of a single component caused entire systems to fail.  The purpose of MQ was so that the application could treat the network as if it was 100% reliable (which was far from the case back in the 1980's).  In order to achieve that MQ kept all critical operations local to the host on which it was installed and minimized external dependencies to things that were the most reliable: POSIX IPC and locally-mounted filesystems.

Some more recent message transports, especially JMS providers, give you the option of selecting a persistence store and even allowing it to be remote.  Some are barely more than a JMS API over a database client.  Though each of these approaches has valid use cases, IBM MQ has retained its focus on ultimate speed and enterprise-grade reliability.

Other IBM products such as the WAS Messaging Engine, MQTT, MQ Light, Sterling and others exist to fill some of the other requirement spaces.  As for MQ, no there's no option to pick your persistence store other than the on the z/OS platform where your options are mostly related to the coupling facility.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It was helpful